# Trying to include custom SQL in an AWS glue job. I suspect I need to replace

Tags: aws-glue

I need to include a custom SQL statement in an AWS  Glue job

I suspect I would need to change 
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog

.from_catalog" method and use 
"create_dynamic_frame_from_rdd"
but not sure how to implement that.
I have not been able to find any examples online.

What exactly am I trying to achieve:
I have an empty Athena partitioned table. I plan to load data from another Athena partitioned table. Except my target table has 2 additional columns.
I do have a custom SQL which selects data from source table and includes the 2 additional new columns but not sure how it fits into the AWS Glue Job.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a dynamic frame from catalogue (Using source athena table)

2) Convert the dynamic frame to dataframe

3) Register the dynamic frame as a temp-table in spark

4) Execute your sql query on this temporary table.

5) Write the data back to S3.

***Sample Code :***

```
DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="{{database}}", table_name="{{table_name}}")
df = DyF.toDF()
df.registerTempTable('{{name}}')
df = sqlContext.sql('{{your select query with table name that you used for temp table above}}
df.write.format('{{orc/parquet/whatever}}').partitionBy("{{columns}}").save('path to s3 location')
```

Also, since your data is partitioned and you have already created the output athena table, you will need to execute MSCK REPAIR command in athena to load the partitions in table metadata.

Comment: @Koorosh Data is never partitioned in memory, i.e. when it is Dynamic frame or Data frame. The partitioning happens at the time of writing it to S3, i.e. there will be different directories created for each unique value of the column passed in partition by clause.

Comment: Thank you. while you pointed me in the right direction issue remains. 
Latest:
When Dynamic DataFrame is converted to DataFrame the output is no longer partitioned.
when I write the output I receive message:
Partition column year_registered not found
(year_registered in the first of the 4 partitions for this table.)

I also switch to Parquet format due to error related to TEXT format.

I am switching back to Dynamic DataFrame before writing to the Parquet table.
using the code you provided writes to the table but the data unreadable scrambled data.
Other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please update the sample code that you are executing. its difficult to predict what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. This issue has been resolved. The latest problem was with the target Parquet table which I fixed, after the code was working as expected.

Comment: That's great to hear. Please accept the answer if it helped :-)